# Return Action as result of another action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 public ActionResult Index(int requestid)
        {
            return View(db.RequestListDetails.Where(c=>c.RequestID == requestid).ToList());
        }
```

How can I back to `View(db.RequestListDetails.Where(c=>c.RequestID == requestid).ToList());` from `Create` action.

My `Create` action code like this

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "....")] RequestListDetail requestListDetail)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.RequestListDetails.Add(requestListDetail);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(requestListDetail);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After db.SaveChanges() you could use this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { requestid = requestListDetail.RequestId });
```

Comment: You may want to provide a bit of additional explanation about what `RedirectToAction` does and it's parameters. Or at the very least throw a [link to the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). Otherwise great answer :)

Comment: @MickelsonMichael thanks for the advice, will do next time!